Presenting UIViewController interactively by panning it over the screen
I have been learning UIKit for a while now. Let's say I have this simple view controller.
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ....
    let swiper = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showNext))
    swiper.maximumNumberOfTouces = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swiper)
  }

  @objc func showNext(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    present(ViewController(), animated: true)
  }

}

I know how to animate the transition to the next view controller. However, I'm unable to do so interactively, by panning over the screen so that the next view controller is presented over the current one gradually. The code snippet provided in the linked documentation is not enough to make a working example, while it seems that google search only results in tutorials on how to interactively dismiss, not interactively present view controller.
The closest I have come to interactively present new view controller is by following the doc:
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
  ...
  // Stock snippet as in the linked documentation
  ...
}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
  func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    self
  }

  func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                             presenting: UIViewController,
                             source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    self
  }

  func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
    PercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
  }
}

class PercentDrivenInteractiveTransition: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {

  override func startInteractiveTransition(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    ...
    // Snippet as in the linked doc
    ...
  }

  @objc func handleSwipeUpdate(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    ...
    // Snippet as in the linked doc
    ...
  }
}

The above code works, but with  strange bug. The first panning, nothing happens. Only on the second panning can the next view controller be interactively pulled over screen. Ideally, the next view controller should gradually be shown on the screen following the first finger panning. How should I approach this?

A swipe is a quick flick of the finger that fires all at once. Do you want that, or do you want the new view controller to appear in proportion to how far the user dragged, like they are moving the page with their finger? If yes, you want a pan gesture, not a swipe gesture.

And if you want the user to be able to pan between pages, you should look at using a UIPageViewController. It's specifically designed to manage two or more pages and lets the user pan between them.

@DuncanC right, I mean panning. I have edited the question accordingly. I'm aware of UIPageViewController, however I want to write code to achieve similar behavior for learning purposes. Any suggestion on how I can use UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition to interactively present new view controller?

Firman, I haven't used that transition before. The Xcode help for the class looks like it would be a good starting point. If you can't work it out I'd suggest googling for sample projects using it.
